# How do you access the developer's commentary on PS4?

Tags: life-is-strange

I own the limited edition physical release of Life is Strange and it says on the box that it includes developer's commentary.

There is a tab for it in the main menu, but when I select it, all I get is a message that "new download content is available" and I get redirected to the PSN store page. There, it shows the season pass and each episode available for purchase and no other available downloads. Since I already own the game, this is not helpful.

There was no code card in the box other than the Square Enix product registration code.

How do I gain access to the developer's commentary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be available as a separate download, like it is [here](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/games/addons/life-is-strange-directors%27-commentary/cid=UP0082-CUSA01442_00-LISDIRCOM0000001).

Have you tried searching for "Life is Strange" in the store and looking through all the listings? More precisely, when I searched, I saw only the season pass and all five episodes, but it said there were 48 total matches, so I looked at those.

Comment: Yeah, that will probably be it. I thought it was already on the disc and not just downloadable since it's advertised as a limited edition bonus on the package. Must be a bug that it doesn't show up in the in-game store. I probably won't be able to try this until Monday though.